# generate div as pdf

Tags: php, jquery

i am trying to generate a content of div into pdf file. when i clicks on the button (generate pdf) its not working. its showing error as

Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost:82/_CrimeDetail/js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
Source Map URL: jquery-1.10.2.min.map[Learn More]
Loading failed for the  with source “https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js”.

ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined[Learn More]

below is my code , please correct it

```
 include("userheader.php"); 


?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css" />

   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html dir="ltr" xml:lang="en-gb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  lang="en-gb">

  <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>


  <head>
 <title>Welcome to the Crime Information System</title>
  </head>
<script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>

 var doc = new jsPDF();
 var specialElementHandlers = {
'#editor': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
 }
 };

 $('#cmd').click(function () {
doc.fromHTML($('#left').html(), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
  });
```

```
<!--content-->
<div id="content">
  <div class="clear">

 <br />
<div id="container" class="wrapper-container">
<div class="corner-top-left">
<div class="corner-top-right">
<div class="corner-bottom-left">
<div class="corner-bottom-right">

   <div class="clear" style="height:325px;overflow-y: scroll;">

<table class="contentpaneopen">
<div class="left" id="left" >

     <?php
                 $selectSQL = "SELECT stories FROM `stories` where 
 `subject`='{$_GET['sub']}'";
   # Execute the SELECT Query
  if( !( $selectRes = mysql_query( $selectSQL ) ) ){
echo 'Retrieval of data from Database Failed - #'.mysql_errno().': 
 '.mysql_error();
    }else{
   ?>
    <table border="2" align="center">
```

```
  if( mysql_num_rows( $selectRes )==0 ){
    echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No Rows Returned</td></tr>';
  }else{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $selectRes ) ){
     {$row['date/time']}</td></tr>\n";
     echo '<tr>';

                       echo '<td class="leftpart">';

if (isset($_GET['sub'])) {
echo '<h2>Subject:  ' . $_GET['sub'] . '</h2>'; 
} else {
// Fallback behaviour goes here
}


                        echo '<h2>Description:  ' . $row['stories'] . '</h2>'; 
                        //echo '<h3>' . $row['stories'] . '<h3>';

                    echo '</td>';

   echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>';
 echo '<h2>Name: '  . $_SESSION['name'] . '</h2>'; 
  $selectSQL = "SELECT address,country,contact,email FROM `user` where 
  `name`='{$_SESSION['name']}'";
     if( !( $selectRes = mysql_query( $selectSQL ) ) ){
     echo 'Retrieval of data from Database Failed - #'.mysql_errno().': 
     '.mysql_error();
      }else{
    if( mysql_num_rows( $selectRes )==0 ){
     echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No Rows Returned</td></tr>';
     }else{
      while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $selectRes ) ){
        echo '<h2>Address:    '  . $row['address'] . '</h2>'; 
        echo '<h2>Country:    '  . $row['country'] . '</h2>'; 
        echo '<h2>Phone No:    '  . $row['contact'] . '</h2>'; 
         echo '<h2>Email:    '  . $row['email'] . '</h2>'; 
            }
        }
         }
         echo '</tr>';



  }
  }

 }


    ?>
  </tbody>
     </table>
        <!--</form>--></div></table></div>
        <div id="editor"></div>
         <button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
           <div class="clear">


    </div></div></div></div></div></div></div>

   <!--footer-->
    <div class="footer clear">
       <span>Crime Reporting System &copy; 2016  |  <a href="#">Privacy 
  Policy</a></span> Crime Reporting is for registering FIR any time and any 
   where in India.. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<!--{%FOOTER_LINK} -->
    </div>
</div>

  <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
 </body></html>
```

Comment: If you can please check if 2 jquery files are being used.

Comment: i have checked it , both are working